# proving inequality ,prime numbers involved.

Tags: prime-numbers, arithmetic

For : $$n\in \mathbb{N} , n\geq 2$$
  Let : $$ \pi \left( n\right)$$
 be the number of prime numbers "p" so as : $$2\leq p\leq n$$

Prove that :
     $$n\geq 14\Rightarrow\pi \left( n\right) \leq \dfrac {n} {2}-1$$

Comment: That's a weak estimate of $\pi(n)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, of $n$ and $n+1$, only one may be prime for the other is divisible by $2$. Thus, by induction, if $\pi(n)\le\frac n2 -1$, and $n$ is odd, then surely $\pi(n+1)\le\frac n2 -1-1\le\frac{n+1}2-1$, and so even if $n+2$ is prime, we have $\pi(n+2)\le\frac n2-1-1\le\frac{n+1}2-1$. Now check the base case and done!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** How many even numbers are there less than $n$?